# Is https enough to secure login data?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, https, restful-authentication

If I use https to communicate from `iOS` application to my backend, is it secure to send login data with a regular `HTTP POST-request` without any specific headers or basic auth?

Thanks!

Comment: Secure against what? You need to be specific, there are a number of ways to attack HTTPS. But are you trying to stop people hacking your app / server or trying to steal someone else's user details?

Comment: Thank you, @Wain! I am concerned about user email and password only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So HTTPS is probably enough, it should prevent someone from accessing another persons details (assuming they don't get physical access to the device). They would need to have a certificate that was valid in the list trusted by the device, or they would need to entice the target user to trust their self signed certificate. To protect against that you need to use certificate pinning (but this is more than probably 98%* of apps do...)

(*I have no actual stats for the percentage)